# white image while Trying to mosiac two hyperspectral data in ENVI

Tags: envi, hyperspectral-sensor

I am trying to mosaic two aviris-ng georefrenced hyoerspectral data but one of them become white in preview. so I am not able to mosaic the image.[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pLx-NmnWxkeNcm36OkMHi2Bh5nvobtpT)

error ink

Comment: Have both images the same scale factor?

Comment: both have x resize factor and y resize factor 1.000000

Comment: even when i open one , it preview a white image in mosiacing window. another one is working fine .

Comment: I think one image has a different scale factor (maybe not stated in metadata). Compare histograms of both images to be sure